# Angular typeahead returning data back from promise , see it in console but not loading into text

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having issues returning the data to html. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userEntry" typeahead-template- url="searchResults.html" uib-typeahead="data.EMPLOYEE_NAME for data in search($viewValue)" uib-typeahead-wait-ms="500" />

<script type="text/ng-template" id="searchResults.html">
  <div>
    <div>
      {{match.model.EMPLOYEE_NAME}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

---

Factory:

```
App.factory('SearchService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  var url = '/api/GetUsers';

  var deffered = $q.defer();
  var data = [];
  var myService = {};

  myService.async = function() {
    $http.get(url)
      .success(function(d) {
        data = d;
        //console.log(d);
        deffered.resolve();
      });
    return deffered.promise;
  };
  myService.data = function() {
    return data;
  };

  return myService;


}]);
```

---

Controller:

```
App.controller('SearchUser', ['$scope', 'SearchService', function($scope, SearchService) {
  $scope.search = function(val) {
    SearchService.async().then(function() {
      $scope.data = SearchService.data();
      console.log($scope.data);
    });
  };
}]);
```

---

Here is the data coming back:

```
[{
  "EMPLOYEE_ID": "246",
  "NETWORK_ID": "onky",
  "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Aaron",
  "DIRECTOR_NAME": "Blood",
  "VP_NAME": "Sigi"
}, {
  "EMPLOYEE_ID": "802",
  "NETWORK_ID": "c0",
  "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Georges",
  "DIRECTOR_NAME": "Johnson",
  "VP_NAME": "Sigi"
}, {
  "EMPLOYEE_ID": "124",
  "NETWORK_ID": "abr",
  "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "MaryamJ.",
  "DIRECTOR_NAME": "James",
  "VP_NAME": "Sigi"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of success is deprecated, you want to change that to use then. You're also returning the promise outside of your success function, so you're returning it too early. It should look more like this:

```
myService.async = function () {
    return $http.get(url)
    .then(function (d) {
        data = d;
        //console.log(d);
        deffered.resolve();
        return deffered.promise;
    });
};
```